# Optimize this query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a query that keeps timing out in SQL Server. The biggest table in the query only has a few hundred rows. Basically I'm trying to match up data in a bunch of tables with the novaPost field in tblNovaPosts to create a report. How should I change this query to make it run faster?

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT tblNovaPosts.type, tblNovaPosts.novaPost,
ISNULL(SUM(tblAuditTrail.amount), 0) AS FUNDING,
ISNULL(SUM(tbl510.allot), 0) AS ALLOT,
ISNULL(SUM(tblStanfin.oblig), 0)
+ ISNULL(SUM(tblSof.obligationsCum), 0)
+ ISNULL(SUM(tblSpecAppt.obligations), 0) 
+ ISNULL(SUM(tblJlens.obligationsCum), 0)
- ISNULL(SUM(viewReimbObs.reimbObs), 0) AS OBLIGATED, 
ISNULL(SUM(tblSof.commitmentsNonCum), 0)
+ ISNULL(SUM(tblRmt.commitment),0)
+ ISNULL(SUM(tblReimb.commitmentsNonCum), 0)
- ISNULL(SUM(viewReimbObs.reimbObs), 0) AS DIRCOMMIT
FROM tblNovaPosts LEFT OUTER JOIN
tblAuditTrail ON tblNovaPosts.novaPost = tblAuditTrail.novaPost LEFT OUTER JOIN
tbl510 ON tblNovaPosts.novaPost = tbl510.novaPost LEFT OUTER JOIN
tblStanfin ON tblNovaPosts.novaPost = tblStanfin.novaPost LEFT OUTER JOIN
tblSof ON tblNovaPosts.novaPost = tblSof.novaPost LEFT OUTER JOIN
tblSpecAppt ON tblNovaPosts.novaPost = tblSpecAppt.novaPost LEFT OUTER JOIN
tblJlens ON tblNovaPosts.novaPost = tblJlens.novaPost LEFT OUTER JOIN
viewReimbObs ON tblNovaPosts.novaPost = viewReimbObs.novaPost1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
tblRmt on tblNovaPosts.novaPost = tblRmt.novaPost LEFT OUTER JOIN
tblReimb ON tblNovaPosts.novaPost = tblReimb.novaPost
GROUP BY tblNovaPosts.type, tblNovaPosts.novaPost
ORDER BY tblNovaPosts.type, tblNovaPosts.novaPost
```

Comment: `TOP (100) PERCENT` doesn't make any sense..

Comment: I've seen it in views when one wants to force an default order by

Comment: @Conrad - [That hasn't worked since SQL Server 2000](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx)

Comment: What's the datatype on tblNovaPosts.novaPost? Also do you really need all thoes joins to be LEFT JOINS? Can some of them be inner joins?

Comment: @Martin Smith. Nice! I always hated that technique.

Comment: @Conrad if this is a View and he is running SQL server 2000, having a `ORDER BY` might be the source of the problem since the query optimizer wont be able to expand the view (when used in other query statements)

Comment: @Magnus Top (100) Percent is generated by SQL Express every time it runs.

Comment: @ConradFrix - I need data for all novaPost fields even when there isn't a match. Also, I don't have access to optimizer. It's in SQL Express 2005 through VS2008.

Comment: @user965777 is it a View? If so do you really need the order by?

Comment: @ConradFrix - The novaPost type is varChar(255)

Comment: @user965777 - You need to look at the execution plan and see what the expensive operators are. Perhaps you are missing some indexes that would help the `JOIN`s. Also check the actual number of rows isn't ridiculous which might indicate an insufficient join condition somewhere.

Comment: @Magnus - It's actually in a stored procedure. I need the final results ordered ascending by novaPost.

Comment: @Martin - Is it possible to check the execution plan through VS2008? Or do I have to download Management?

Comment: @user965777 - I'm not sure via vs 2008. What happens if you try `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON; GO; YourQuery`?

Comment: You can also use Plan Explorer to find the expensive parts of a query plan, it's a free download and doesn't actually require Management Studio (though you should be using Management Studio, not Visual Studio, for DB development IMHO). You can enter your query in the Command Text pane and hit "Actual Execution Plan." See more about it here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/13/a-demo-kit-for-sql-sentry-plan-explorer.aspx

Comment: @Martin to be pedantic, you can force the behavior post-SQL 2000 as well, but I never recommend it and actually try to keep it a secret.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I'm having problems with Showplan_xml through Visual Studio. It says that it must be the only statement in the batch.

Comment: @AaronBertrand [`top (2147483647)`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/10/03/exploring-the-secrets-of-intermediate-materialization.aspx)? Does that still work in 2008?

Comment: @user965777 - That's why you need the `GO` statement between it and your query. I just tried in ~VS2010 and "Include Actual Execution Plan" appears as an option if you right click the TSQL editor window. It's also addable to the toolbar. Does VS2008 not have this?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I probably should be using Management Studio, but I don't get to choose my development tools at work.

Comment: [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593) Its free

Comment: @Martin no, `ORDER BY` in a view is not guaranteed to be honored by the outer query (without `ORDER BY`) no matter what kind of tricks you use inside the view.

Comment: @user965777 so your boss will buy you Visual Studio but won't let you use Management Studio (which you are probably licensed for) or Management Studio Express (which is free)? Also, could you pick a username please?

Comment: @Martin you might *see* that behavior using that approach, but you can't rely on it. If you want to guarantee a certain order, ***ALWAYS*** use `ORDER BY` on the outer query. Adam's trick won't necessarily always fool the optimizer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - You brought up the issue of forcing the behavior post-SQL 2000! I just asked if that's what you meant.

Comment: @Martin sorry, tough to interpret what/how you were asking, but no, that was not the behavior I was talking about.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Compatibility mode?

Comment: @Martin no. Rhymes with space tag. It's not really a secret, I just hate to mention it because then people use it and keep being lazy with their outer queries. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926292

Comment: @AaronBertrand - ah took me a while going through the alphabet for rhymes but got there in the end! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

View the query plan.  Oftentimes SQL Server will give you an index recommendation.

Click this button:

[image: execution plan]

Answer (score 0):

There is something suspicious about all the LEFT OUTER JOINs.  Are you quite sure that is what you need?

Also, I notice you are outer joining to a table called tblAuditTrail.  That seems likely to produce a cartesian product of 2 tables.

Perhaps you should test each join individually to check you are not actually requesting ten gzillion rows instead of just the few hundred you were expecting.